question about how to use custom counter for row numbers of tables
I put \newcounter macro to use for adding row numbers in a table.
The test document is as follows:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcounter{mycounter}[table]

\NewDocumentCommand\rownum{m}{\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
%  \setcounter{mycounter}{0}
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{c|c}
    aaa & \rownum{tab1:1} (\ref{tab1:1})\\
    bbb & \rownum{tab1:2} (\ref{tab1:2})\\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb]
%  \setcounter{mycounter}{0}
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{c|c}
    ccc & \rownum{tab2:1} (\ref{tab2:1})\\
    ddd & \rownum{tab2:2} (\ref{tab2:2})\\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}

I thought `\newcounter{mycounter}[table]' would work by resetting counter every table environment but the result is not like that as follows:
aaa | (6)
bbb | (8)

ccc | (14)
ddd | (16)

uncommenting '\setcounter{mycounter}{0}' looks like resetting the counter
aaa | (6)
bbb | (8)

ccc | (6)
ddd | (8)

But still the counter does not start from 1 and the numbers in a table is not sequential.
so the problem is

counter numbers do not start from 1 and are not sequential in a table
the counter is not aut-reset for every tabl environment

any comments are grateful.

Tabularray automaticity counts rows: \arabic{rownum}

The table counter is stepped by the \caption command inside table, not by the environment itself. The reason is that in a single table environment you may have several \caption commands, for distinct tables.
So, no \caption, no reset.
Actually, any table environment should have a \caption, because it can float and, with no explanation next to it, the reader will not understand what it's about.
Added from comment: you can use the counter library to overcome the fact that tblr makes multiple passes over the material.
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter} % <--- important!

\newcounter{mycounter}[table]

\NewDocumentCommand\rownum{m}{%
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}%
  \label{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering

\caption{A table with \texttt{tblr}}

\begin{tblr}{c|c}
  aaa & \rownum{tab1:1} (\ref{tab1:1})\\
  bbb & \rownum{tab1:2} (\ref{tab1:2})\\
\end{tblr}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering

\caption{A table with \texttt{tabular}}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
  ccc & \rownum{tab2:1} (\ref{tab2:1})\\
  ddd & \rownum{tab2:2} (\ref{tab2:2})\\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}

It's immaterial whether you put captions above or below tables, as long as you're consistent.


"The approach with \newcounter is bound to failure anyway, if you use tabularray" tabularray has the counter library which avoids problems.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks.

Tabularray already has a counter to count rows: rownum.
You could either directly use it or use to set your custom counter:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\newcounter{mycounter}

\NewDocumentCommand\rownum{m}{%
\setcounter{mycounter}{\value{rownum}}%
\addtocounter{mycounter}{-1}%
\refstepcounter{mycounter}%
\label{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{c|c}
    aaa & (\arabic{rownum}) \rownum{tab1:1} (\ref{tab1:1})\\
    bbb & (\arabic{rownum}) \rownum{tab1:2} (\ref{tab1:2})\\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{c|c}
    ccc & (\arabic{rownum}) \rownum{tab2:1} (\ref{tab2:1})\\
    ddd & (\arabic{rownum}) \rownum{tab2:2} (\ref{tab2:2})\\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}


\end{document}



@egreg Fixed, thx
